# How to select delimited texts separately and completely SQL Server table column

Tags: sql-server, split, csv

I have a SQL Server table with a column `p_author` containing semi-colon (`;`) delimited text value. I used this query to split and select the respective id's from another table but it only splits once whereas I need all the value id's after splitting either `p_author` contains one value, two values, three values or whatever number of values. Under is the used query for splitting and selecting respective id's from another table.

```
    select aid as [CountedID] 
    from sub_aminer_author 
    where name like (select RIGHT(p_author, LEN(p_author) - CHARINDEX(';', p_author)) 
                     from sub_aminer_paper 
                     where pid = 4)
```

Sample data is shown here in this image.

[image]

@DarkKnight--This is my output in SqlServer2014

[image]

Comment: A column storing multiple values is a *bug*. Instead of trying to split or perform a full-text search, fix the design. If, *and only if*, the author information is never used for anything else, consider the FTS functions. In your case though, you should really use an intermediate many-to-many table to link the tables.

Comment: show some sample data

Comment: BTW, not my downvote, but you can't fix a bad table design with a query.

Comment: @DarkKnight here I have shown the sample data

Comment: @DarkKnight your solution is almost fine except just the issue is in order of output

Comment: @DarkKnight yeah I am facing same issue described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
DECLARE @X XML
    DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX)=''
                Select @STR = @STR+';'+P_AUTHOR
                From sub_aminer_paper
                WHERE PID = 4
                ORDER BY PID

  select @STR = substring(@STR,2,len(@STR))

    SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@STR,';','</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')

     select aid as [CountedID], name
        from sub_aminer_author s
        inner join (
        SELECT row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rn, T.c.value('.','varchar(max)') as value
        FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)) t on t.value = s.name
        order by rn
```

Example fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34b6c/10

Comment: @DarkKnight---In my query editor it is giving me just 9 rows with author names, can't understand why ?

Comment: @DarkKnight--it is giving output of just last `pid` in the table which contain 8 author names and also surprisingly it is giving first empty row and then 8 rows with author names, i.e. 9 rows in total???

Comment: @DarkKnight---are you there??? Your query is working but there is still some minor issue i.e. showing 1st row empty, how to sort out this?

Comment: @maliks : let me know if you didnt get the solution yet.

Comment: @maliks : i have updated query. this should work now.

Comment: @DarkKnight---query working fine but again a minor issue i.e. if text in column _p_author_ is **M. Gyssens;J. Paredaens**, then it is showing the _aid_ as output i.e.  

`96116 J. Paredaens
112127 M. Gyssens`  

Its mean the order of output is inverted, it should be like this:  

`112127 M. Gyssens
96116 J. Paredaens`

Comment: @DarkKnight--I have tried another _pid_ containing 3 author names, whereas it is not following the order of entries in fact mixing up the order

Comment: @maliks : let me know if you are still fighting with this

Comment: @DarkKnight--yeah I am facing same issue described above

Comment: @maliks : can you please create fiddle with your data and query?

Comment: Though its working fine at fiddle but not on my query editor Sql Server 2014

Comment: @maliks : query is working fine on my SQLServer2012. I changed SQLFiddle to point to SQLServer2014, working there too..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88971/discussion-between-maliks-and-dark-knight).

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said in the comments, you really need to remove this bad design.

It will only lead to bigger problems and performance issues. (I know that sometime you have to deal will terrible design for a little while)

In the meantime, if you really need to split your rows, this type of query with a recursive CTE ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7dd5b/1/0))can be used:

```
create table sub_aminer_author(pid int, p_author varchar(max), name varchar(max));
go
Insert into sub_aminer_author(pid, p_author, name) values 
(1, 'AAAA;BBBBB;CCCCC', 'AAAA'), (2, 'DDDDD;EEEEE;FFFF;GGGGGGGG', 'GGGGGGGG'), (3, 'HHH', 'GGGGGGGG');
go

with split(pid, first, pos) as(
    Select pid, cast(1 as bigint)
        , Case When CHARINDEX(';', p_author) > 0 
        Then CHARINDEX(';', p_author)-1 Else len(p_author) End
    From sub_aminer_author
    Union All
    Select d.pid, s.pos+2
        , Case When CHARINDEX(';', d.p_author, s.pos+2) > 0 Then CHARINDEX(';', d.p_author, s.pos+2)-1 Else len(p_author) End
    From split s
    Inner Join sub_aminer_author d on d.pid = s.pid
    Where s.pos < len(d.p_author)-1
) 
Select d.pid, s.first, s.pos    , SUBSTRING(d.p_author, s.first,  s.pos - s.first +1) 
From split s
Inner Join sub_aminer_author d on d.pid = s.pid 
order by d.pid, s.first
```

You have to understand that it is neither good nor efficient. 
It should be ok as long as you only temporary use it to fix your current design issue and move splited data to a better design.

Comment: @JulienVavasseur--This query works but I have to fetch `aid` from another table as I have provided the schema for `sub_aminer_author` table also

Comment: I put it this way because it is easier to show you how to do it this way with sample data. You can then replace @data by whatever you need or add join if your data comes from several tables. You have all you need for split string. You only need to adapt it to your model with basic sql.

Comment: My update should put your in the right direction. I did it from my phone and I hope the syntax is ok. I can't update the fiddle at the moment.

Comment: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "first" of recursive query "split".---------This is the ERROR when I replaced @data with  my own table name

Comment: aid (int) and p_author (varchar(max))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88783/discussion-between-maliks-and-julien-vavasseur).